# How should table structure work while using databases?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I wondered how a table should be structured when there is going to be more than one value for a certain field. For example, If I have a user who has 10 friends should there be a table that has 10 rows with the user's name and a different friend on each row or should there be one row with the user's name and all the friends put into one? Thanks, the answers will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a many-to-many table that links the foreign keys together of two people who are friends. So if `Person` is the entity you are using, you wouldn't want to constrain the structure by introducing limitations such as 10 friends into a single row.

Comment: so the same as what i said with the 10 rows??

Comment: You would have 10 rows to begin with, but if you added more friends for a single `Person`, it would just be adding more rows to this many-to-many table. Call it the `Friends` table if that helps. Since friend is bidirectional, it would imply that a single row is a friendship shared by both `Person` objects involved.

Comment: i know i got that part lol i just didnt know whether i would need a new row for each new friend that certain user got

Comment: Yes, this way you would be able to add more friend relationships. Intuitively, since a friendship is a relationship between two people, and since a single person is not bound to a single friend, this is a perfect example of a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, what you're trying to do is normalize your data. You should read up a bit on [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)